# Object's state in the Template method design pattern

Tags: php, design-patterns, template-method-pattern

Here is an implementation example of the algorigthm in the base absctract class from http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method/php

```
public final function showBookTitleInfo($book_in) {
    $title = $book_in->getTitle();
    $author = $book_in->getAuthor();
    $processedTitle = $this->processTitle($title);
    $processedAuthor = $this->processAuthor($author);
    if (NULL == $processedAuthor) {
        $processed_info = $processedTitle;
    } else {
        $processed_info = $processedTitle.' by '.$processedAuthor;
    }
    return $processed_info;
}
```

I don't like it becase I think, that "showBookTitleInfo" knows too much about the methods it calls.

Here is another example
    abstract class template_method {
        var $state;
        public function __construct() {
            $this->state = 0;
        }

```
    public function processEvent( $event ) {
        $this->doFirstStep( $event );
        $this->doSecondStep( $event );
    }
    abstract public function doFirstStep( &$event );
    abstract public function doSecondStep( &$event );
}

class CustomLogic extends template_method {
    public function doFirstStep( &$event ) {
        echo __METHOD__.": state: ".$this->state." event: $event\n";
        $this->state++;
    }
    public function doSecondStep( &$event ) {
        echo __METHOD__.": state: ".$this->state." event: $event\n";
        $this->state++;
    }
}
```

why we pass event as by-reference, if we don't change its value?
How should I implement "my steps" logic, if they are using current state, can modify its value, and other steps can read modified value and can modify it too?

For example, I want to implement cost counting mechanism for scheduled message sending - simple and reccurent(ex: every Mon, Fri until 23.05.2009).

So, I implement the algorithm in abstract class as following:

```
abstract class AbstractCostCounter {
    public function countNotReccurentSendingCost($messageObj) {
        $totalMessages = $messageObj->getTotalMessages(); // multiple recipients are allowed
        $message_cost = 1; // just to give you an idea
        $this->cost = $totalMessages * $message_cost;
    }
    abstract public function countOptional();

    // I pass $messageObject not as by-reference, because it hasn't to be modified
    public function countCost( $messageObject ) {
        $this->countNotReccurentSendingCost( $messageObject );
        $this->countOptional( $messageObject );
    }

}

class TemplateNotReccurentCostCounting {
    public function countOptional($messageObj) {
        // do nothing
    }
}

class TemplateReccurentCostCounting {
    public function countOptional($messageObj) {
        $notReccurentSendingCost = $this->cost;
        $totalMessagesInScheduledPlan = $messageObj->getTotalMessagesInScheduledPlan();
        $reccurentSendingPlanCost = $notReccurentSendingCost * $totalMessagesInScheduledPlan;
        $this->cost = $reccurentSendingPlanCost;
    }
}
```

Am I moving in the right direction?
Is it where Template method design pattern should be implemented?
Please let me know, if it is something wrong with this code.

P.S. cost counter is not a production code. I wrote it because I wanted to give you an idea.

Thanks, in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template method pattern gives the parent class a lot of control, the parent class has to know a lot about the abstract methods (their signature) because it has to 'control' the algorithm. BTW the concrete method in the parent class has to be final.

You have no advantage with your firstStep secondStep methods, I could implement what I want in stepOne and do nothing in stepTwo...

The question is when would you want to use Template Method Pattern, not how to rewrite it to give more flexibility :)